# Limit the length of NativeBase text

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I use `NativeBase` text component and I want to limit it by character. For example, it shows only the first 10 characters.

How to do that?

Comment: Are you taking about `Input` component because `Text` doesn't accept user input.

Comment: no, I use a text component to show string, and I want to show 10 first character. how to limit the character to show?

Comment: So that means you already have they value with you and you want to assign always the 10 chars of the value

Comment: yes, I want to show some character visible and other characters hide. and with click to text, I show all of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the slice function:

```js
var str = "012345678911111111"; 
var res = str.slice(0, 10);
```

output:

> 0123456789

Answer (score 3):

```
<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='head'>your very long text goes here <Text>
```

Allowed modes are  `head, tail, middle,clip`

[Read more](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#ellipsizemode)

Comment: not work correcrly for me! when I use ***slice(10)*** show me all of the chars without 10 first chars!!!

Comment: I understood your problem statement now, I have updated my answer please check now.